# Populating second grid with the selections from the first grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

On button click I need to add the record selections from my Grid named List9 to the grid List10.

I am getting the data in selectedrows variable but how do I get this data to my second grid?

1st grid

```
var rowID = jQuery("#list9").getGridParam("selrow");
selectedRows = JSON.stringify(jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('getRowData', rowID));
```

I am not able to get the `selectedRows` record as the data to my 2nd grid. I am passing this variable as the data to my 2nd grid.

Comment: this is not an acceptable question format. Kindly go through the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) for more information about formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want implement Master/Details scenario and want that ids of rows selected in the master grid "#list9" will be sent as additional parameter to `url` of the second (details) grid "#list10".

You can use `postData` option in the second (details) grid "#list10". The properties of the `postData` define additional parameter which will be send to the server. If you want for example to have `selectedIds` as the name of additional parameter and you use `multiselect: true` option on the master grid "#list9" you can include the following option in the detail grid "#list10":

```
postData: {
    selectedIds: function () {
        return $("#list9").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
    }
}
```

If you don't use `multiselect: true` option then to send `selectedId` you can use

```
postData: {
    selectedId: function () {
        return $("#list9").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
    }
}
```

Comment: @shirin: You are welcome! Let me know when you have some progress in the problem.